# More than 8 WAN aliases on routers?

Tags: ip, router, routing, wide-area-network

We have a Draytek Vigor 2820 in our office and we have a few servers running websites and email applications. These servers each have their own public ip using WAN aliases that are mapped to their local IP.

I am looking to extend our IP block (from our ISP) from 5 static IP addresses to 15. The problem is, I can't find a medium business type router that supports more than 8 WAN aliases.

Is there an alternative way of routing public IP addresses to local servers that bypasses the 8 alias limit. Or do we need a much more expensive router? Our current router cost about £200. The top Draytek router I found with the same limitation is around £500.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean with WAN Aliases - do you mean that your current router only supports 8 external IP addresses?

Comment: Yeah, sorry that may be Draytek specific terminology.

Comment: @MarkHenderson judging by the question I think he's referring to 1:1 NAT entries.

Comment: @MarkM yep, that's exactly what I mean. I didn't call it a one to one entry because I thought it was a Draytek term. Stupid, eh!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never heard of Draytek. If you get a midrange router from a major vendor like Cisco, Juniper, Extreme, etc, you shouldn't run into these asinine limitations. You get what you pay for.

Comment: Do any of those brands have GUI's? I'm not quite ready to control the router using command line only.

Comment: I know that Linksys models have GUIs and you can have 8 *ranges* of IP addresses for 1:1 NAT. So if your internal IP's and external IP's are sequential and all in the right order, you can do it all in one entry. It's a stupid system though.

Comment: @dannymcc I don't know. I don't manage any that do. I wouldn't even know where to begin to look for that since its not a requirement of mine.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've solved the problem by routing the IP's using a second subnet on the router rather than using the 1:1 NAT. Thanks!